# norms in vector space and their equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that $\forall x\in \mathbb R^n$ : $|x|_{M}\leq|x|\leq|x|_{s}\leq n|x|_{M}$

where,

$|x|_{M}$ $=$ $max$ {${|x_{1}|,...,|x_{n}|}$} $=$ maximum of absolute values of the components $=$ sup norm of $x$ $=$ infinity norm of $x$

$|x|_{s}$ $=$ $|x_{1}|$ $+$ $|x_{2}|$ $+$ $...$ $+$ $|x_{n}|$ $=$ sum of absolute values of the components $=$ one norm of $x$

$|x|$ $=$ $\sqrt{<x,x>}$ $=$ $\sqrt{\sum x_{i}^2}$ $=$ Euclidean norm of $x$ $=$ two norm of $x$

I have the following definition as a help: two norms are equivalent if exist $K,M \in \mathbb R$ such that $K|x|^{*}$ $\leq$ $|x|^{+}$ $\leq$ $M|x|^{*}$

Could someone help me on how to start please?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  You'll get significantly more help (and significantly more USEFUL help) if you show us what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.

For instance: have you managed to figure out any of the inequalities in the above?

Comment: @NickPeterson I only have the definitions and I don't know where to start or what direction to take

Answer (score 0):

$|x|_s\leq n|x|_M$ is obvious, since $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|\leq n\max_{i}|x_i|$.

$|x|_M\leq|x|_s$ is also obvious, since $\max_{i}|x_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|$.

But I don't know how you define $|x|$. Your definition of it is quite vague. Once you are clear on this, you can prove the set of inequalities. You should update a clear definition of it, and I can complete the proof.

Comment: $|x|$ $=$ $\sqrt{<x,x>}$ $=$ $\sqrt{\sum x_{i}^2}$ $=$ Euclidean norm of $x$ $=$ two norm of $x$